How to import all the object into Oracle database
I have an Oracle dump, which includes tables and views. While importing my database, it's accepting only tables, not views.
I am using the following import command for importing the file:
Imp system/system file=test.dmp full=y log=log.txt

Kindly let me know whether I am missing any parameters. 

Does the log file say views are being excluded, and if so why - e.g. giving ORA errors? Are they in the SYS or SYSTEM schemas, or normal schemas? Otherwise, are you really sure they were included in the export? Maybe check the log for that too. And why are you using legacy exp/imp instead of expdp/impdp?
